# Trying to use Kies to upgrade Galaxy Note firmware

Tags: samsung-kies, samsung-galaxy-note

Similar to this question: [Kies dies when trying to update Galaxy Note firmware](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33417/kies-dies-when-trying-to-update-galaxy-note-firmware)

I go to upgrade the firmware and it just keeps looping, downloading firmware components.  The progress bar keeps moving, but it seems like it starts over and never completes.

I've uninstalled Kies and reinstalled it as an Administrator.  I set it to run in XPSP3 compatibility mode and to run as an administrator and even run it explicitly as an administrator with a right-click.

I'm running on Windows 7 Professional, SP1, 32-bit OS.

[image]